# TreeSet contains returns false, when definitely contains item

Tags: java, tree, sorting

I have a queue implementation based on a TreeSet, I use a TreeSet as the order of the items changes frequently.

Unfortunately I'm running into a bit of a problem. My queue class implements a next(), contains() and remove() method (wraps TreeSet remove() and contains() and a basic iterator that returns the first item, but does not remove it).

I have a custom comparator I use to sort the tree (below). If I do `queue.remove(queue.next())` inside a synchronised block (thread safe), the queue length does not change.

If I do `queue.contains(queue.next())` it returns false.

How is this possible? The items in the queue override the equals and hashcode methods, but as I understand TreeSet doesnt use those anyway.

The `t1.getName()` below always returns a unique string (I am 100% certain of this).

```
private class BayesianComparator implements Comparator<SolverRunnable>{

@Override
public int compare(SolverRunnable t, SolverRunnable t1) {
  int s = score(t1) - score(t);
  if(s == 0){
    return t1.getName().compareTo(t.getName());
  }
  return s;
}

public int score(SolverRunnable t){
  double score = 0;
  for(Node n : t.getModifiers().keySet()){
    Double d = variableTrueProbs.get(n);
    if(d != null){
      if(t.getModifiers().get(n) == '1'){
        score += (d - 0.5);
      }
      else{
        score -= (d - 0.5);
      }
    }


  }

  return (int)Math.round(score * 1000);
}
}
```

Comment: The contains method is based on `equals` not on the comparator. Isn't it? What's your implementation of equals for the class in question?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo it's a `TreeSet`. It uses a `Comparator` rather than `hashCode` and `equals`.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo, in any case `next().equals(next())` always returns true (as you would expect)

Comment: @Luiggi That's not what the documentation of `TreeSet` says

Comment: from the `contains(SolverRunnable)` method, the `compare(SolverRunnable, SolverRunnable)` never gets into here: `if(s == 0){`.

Comment: Looks like I can't do what I wanted to do :( The items "key" is mutable, based on a score that changes.

Comment: Once you put item into a tree set its score must be constant. If need to change the score, first you need to remove the item then reinsert with a new score.